# SailsJS 0.11: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '.../node_modules/.bin/cdl'

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Theres this `SailsJS` application that works on my office machine but not locally, I wonder why? Locally I run linux. In office Mac. Locally I get

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   '/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/.bin/cdl'   at Error
>   (native)   at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:849:18)   at
>   /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/include-all/index.js:44:12 
>   at Array.forEach (native)   at requireAll
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/include-all/index.js:40:9)
>   at
>   /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/include-all/index.js:50:23 
>   at Array.forEach (native)   at requireAll
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/include-all/index.js:40:9)
>   at buildDictionary
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:68:14)
>   at Function.module.exports.optional
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:160:9)
>   at Array.async.auto.nodeModulesFolder
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:379:27)
>   at
>   /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:484:38
>   at _each
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
>   at Object.async.auto
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:455:9)
>   at Hook.loadUserHooks
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:363:13)
>   at Hook.bound [as loadUserHooks]
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
>   at Hook.initialize
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/userhooks/index.js:29:18)
>   at Hook.bound [as initialize]
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
>   at
>   /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/index.js:75:14
>   at
>   /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:451:17
>   at
>   /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:441:17
>   at _each
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
>   at Immediate.taskComplete
>   (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:440:13)
>   at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:374:17)

I am using `Sails 0.11`. Server can actually start with `Sails 0.12` but theres some breaking changes, thus I am stuck with `0.11` for now. I am using `Node 4`.

Comment: There could be some modules that are os-specific so if there's a module that is compiled when you run *npm install ... * it might not be compatible (so it's not found) in other os

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are using **dropbox** to sync office laptop with your machine,
due to which some files are getting added into your project which will not cause problem in one OS but can create the issue in other.

Thus, I suggest that you should follow the **standard practices to clone** the project

1. Use the git or bitbucket to clone the project.
2. install the dependencies => npm install

Don't use dropbox for the project sync. Use the version control system to clone/pull the code, and install all dependencies

> because [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) compiles native add-on modules for Node.js with respect to OS

and hopefully, after this it should work fine.

If you don't want to use the VCS then you can follow the below steps:

```
 # cd /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub
 # sudo rm -rf node_modules
 # rm -rf ~/.npm
 # npm cache clear
 # npm install
```

That's all you need to do.

Comment: For me I tried `rm -rf node_modules/*` many times. Dropbox does not sync the `node_modules` folder. But the key for me is I had to do `rm -rf /node_modules/.npm` somehow its not removed from the first `rm` command. Maybe hidden folders stay

Comment: @JiewMeng yeah, because .npm is a folder and to delete a folder you need to use the remove force that's by It's not working with only  rm.

Answer (score 5):

You need to rebuild your `node_modules` if you are moving to a new machine. You can do it like this:

```
cd /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/meclub
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

The reason why this is required is that the `.bin` folder is full of [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). This will likely cause issues with Dropbox. Also, resources in the `.bin` folder are sometimes compiled natively. Moving from Ubuntu to Mac OSX without recompiling, will be an issue at runtime for many components.

Just as with a VCS, I would recommend that you do not sync the `node_modules` folder at all. This should not be shared between machines. You can manage these dependencies using NPM on each computer.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to delete the whole node_modules directory. Just run `npm rebuild` and it will rebuild modules if they don't match your current architecture.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you are running Sails from the **correct directory**, using `sails lift` or whatever you use
2. Do a `npm install` to make sure all the modules are installed
3. Manually check if all modules in package.json are available in your node_modules folder
4. Make sure the versions of the Node is same in both (it shouldn't be a problem even if not - in most cases)
5. Try re-installing sails and node in the worst case.